# Pdf to Image conversion in an Azure Function

Tags: c#, node.js, azure, azure-functions

I'm using the below code for an azure function in JS. The BLOB trigger is working and it shows that the process started but it doesn't shows anything else seems that the convert is not working but it doesn't give an error for knowing what actually happened:

[image]

This is the function code I'm using:

https://github.com/tyayers/Azure-Pdf-Imager-Function

I'm using a Node.JS function app version ~3.

The end goal is to convert PDFs for cognitive search regardless of the language in an azure function.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks like the library in this project (`pdf2png-mp`) uses ghostscript shipped for just [windows](https://github.com/Inkognitoo/Pdf2Png/tree/master/executables/ghostScript). Are you hosting your function on a windows app service plan? Or as mentioned in the readme of the module, you could download and place the `gs` executable in the `executables/ghostScript` folder under the modules folder in `node_modules` before publishing.

Comment: Actually I'm hosting that on a windows machine and the ghost script is there checked it with PowerShell. That is the interesting part as it just finishes but doesn't calls the callback function nor with Error neighter with Success.

Answer (score 1):

Finally after a lot of googling I went back to C# with the below 2 libraries:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/PDFium.Windows/

https://github.com/ArgusMagnus/PDFiumSharp

Then the github url is having an example namely

https://github.com/ArgusMagnus/PDFiumSharp/blob/master/Samples/Test.Console/Program.cs

Basically with that example and with some small Stream to Byte Array trics I was able to create my function.

Please note that the PDFium libraries are needed for the package that's why I posted that URL here as well.